# Remove parenthesis but keep number

Tags: regex, ms-word

I'm editing a large MS Word document (113 pages) that has a lot of numbers surrounded by parenthesis, ie: (1) (2) (3) etc. The numbers are used for references which are given at the end of each 'chapter' and so they need to be kept.

How can I remove the parenthesis but keep the numbers which, in turn, need to turned into superscript?

Is there a way of using regexp to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: @Barmar: then why is there a separate "regex" tag on SO? And an "ms-word" tag? Regex search & replace is much like scripting, which I consider programming.

Comment: @BrianStephens There's a regex tag because regular expressions are used frequently in programming. And writing word macros is a form of programming, that's where the ms-word tag would be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a Find and Replace in Word, using the following settings:

- Find: `\(([0-9]{1,})\)`
- Replace: `\1`
- Format: superscript

The formatting option for the "replace" is at the bottom of the "Find and Replace" dialog.

Regex breakdown:

- The `\(` and `\)` surrounding the expression are the literal parens you are matching.
- The inner `(` and `)` are grouping parens to capture the text that matches the pattern inside.
- `[0-9]{1,}` matches one or more digits
- In the replace pattern, `\1` refers back to the first matched group (in this case, there's only one: the digits inside the parens).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! Worked perfectly! Also, thank you for the explanation. That is very much appreciated.